# queries in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

i have written the following code

```
var resumeedit=(from t in db.Resumes where t.User.UserID==theUserID && t.ResumeID==theResumeID select t).Select(t=> new EditResumes
                 {
                     Iswizard=t.isWizard,
                     Resumeid=t.ResumeID.ToString()
                 }).First();
             EditResumes ed = (EditResumes)resumeedit;
```

and it is giving error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the message says, L2E doesn't do `.ToString()`. So use `.AsEnumerable()` to bring it into L2O:

```
var resumeedit= (from t in db.Resumes 
                 where t.User.UserID==theUserID && t.ResumeID==theResumeID
                 select t)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(t=> new EditResumes
                 {
                     Iswizard=t.isWizard,
                     Resumeid=t.ResumeID.ToString()
                 }).First();
```

This cast should be unnecessary:

```
 EditResumes ed = (EditResumes)resumeedit;
```

Answer (score 1):

this line

```
Resumeid=t.ResumeID.ToString()
```

what happens when you make it

```
Resumeid=t.ResumeID
```

?

or simple do:

```
select new { t.ResumeID, t.isWizard }
```

Comment: With your first suggestion, the code won't compile. With your second, the cast in the second line fails.